# Best advertisement program from web application to display after user login, together with Google Adsense

Tags: web-development, google-adsense, advertising

I have developed a web application. It is a todo list manager.

I am already displaying adversiment on users' accounts after they login with Google Adsense.

To increase revenues I would like to display ads from another program, too.

Obviously their spider will not be able to parse the content of the page before sending the ad because the area is password-protected.

Are you in a similar setting? What would you suggest?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I have read [something about DFP](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dfp-tutorial/14099/), what do you think about it?